# dplyr filter logic using both 'and' and 'or'

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like both bullet points to be *TRUE* for mtcars data set:

- *cyl* > 4 and *mpg* > 10
- *vs* > 0 or *carb* > 1

What's the 'proper' way to write this with dplyr? Is there some kind of visualization explaining and/or? The difference between "and and" "and, or, and" and that kind of thing. I think I got it correct below, but this always confuses me a bit. I think there's a chapter in R inferno called "and and andand" that satires this type of situation.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  filter(
    cyl > 4,
    mpg > 10,
    vs > 0 | 
      carb > 1
  )
```

Comment: for `and` use `&` not a comma, furthermore `|` is `or`, so you want: `( cyl>4 & mpg>10) & (vs>0 | carb >1)`, for literature look [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#filter-rows-with-filter) chapter 5.2.2

Comment: How are those two bullets related? Do you want either bullet to be true? or both? I can't tell what you expected output is here.

Comment: @MrFlick I want both conditions fulfilled in the bullet. Thanks, I edited original to note this. @Stephan Thanks, I did read Hadley's R4DS and he says `"As well as & and |, R also has && and ||. Don’t use them here! You’ll learn when you should use them in conditional execution."`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expression is fine - you can treat each `,` in `filter(...)` like `&` as far as I can tell:

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4) %>% nrow()           # 21
mtcars %>% filter(mpg > 20) %>% nrow()          # 14
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20) %>% nrow()     # 3
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4 & mpg > 20) %>% nrow()    # 3
identical(mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20), mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4 & mpg > 20))
# TRUE

mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20, vs > 0) %>% nrow()         # 1
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20, carb > 1) %>% nrow()           # 2
mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20, vs > 0 | carb > 1) %>% nrow()  # 3 
identical(mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4 & mpg > 20 & (vs > 0 | carb > 1)), mtcars %>% filter(cyl > 4, mpg > 20, vs > 0 | carb > 1))
# TRUE
```